# Advertise obfs3 Tor bridge on port 80

Tags: bridge, obfsproxy

I'm currently running a Tor bridge on port 80 (for personal purposes, luckily no real needs). From what I can see in the obfs debug there's no connection other than mine, probably because the bridge is not (correctly) advertised on the Tor network (I guess).

I'm running it with a hack, because I couldn't find a better way to o so. Time ago I found [an answer on SO](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/560/6573) which explained how to run a bridge on port 80 via iptables rules, and that's what I do and works fine. But since the Bridge is online it's a shame others cannot benefit from it.

This is my configuration:

```
RelayBandwidthRate 900 KB
RelayBandwidthBurst 1 MB
ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
SocksPort 0
ORPort 2000
ExtORPort auto
BridgeRelay 1
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs3 0.0.0.0:9999
ServerTransportPlugin obfs3 proxy public_ip:80
```

When started Tor reports the ORPort as reachable, but that's not the obfuscated port. I guess many people can benefit from using a Bridge on port 80.

So two questions:

1. is there a non hack-ish way to run a bridge on port 80?
   I did some tests in running Tor as *root* user, but other than being discouraged it was still not working because the control socket was still created as *debian-tor* user (on Ubuntu), and I stopped there.
2. (more important) how can I advertise the bridge on port 80?

Comment: Ignore Alexey, he's just incredibly wrong all the time. https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/tree/README.md#n74

Comment: Thanks @canonizingironize, I managed to get obfs4 running. Will post some updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @canonizing comment I installed obfs4 proxy with the following config and it's published:

```
ExitPolicy reject *:*
#Bridge config
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 1234
BridgeRelay 1
ServerTransportPlugin obfs3,obfs4 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy managed
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs3 [::]:443
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 [::]:80
ExtORPort auto
```

`PublishServerDescriptor` is by default enabled on bridges.

Answer (score 0):

I used to encounter such an odd behaviour too, try this in your torrc:

```
ClientOnly 0
PublishServerDescriptor bridge
```

the description of [PublishServerDescriptor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#PublishServerDescriptor) states as well:

**PublishServerDescriptor 0|1|v3|bridge,…**

> This option specifies which descriptors Tor will publish when acting as a relay. You can choose multiple arguments, separated by commas. 
>   If this option is set to 0, Tor will not publish its descriptors to any directories. (This is useful if you’re testing out your server, or if you’re using a Tor controller that handles directory publishing for you.) Otherwise, Tor will publish its descriptors of all type(s) specified. The default is "1", which means "if running as a server, publish the appropriate descriptors to the authorities".

so this is a bit weird, I know, but it worked for me.

Comment: I will check. But will this publish the brige on the obfs3 port?

Comment: Yes, according to your config directive `ServerTransportPlugin obfs3 proxy public_ip:80` - the thing I'm proposing is actually a manual kickass for Tor to publish the descriptor as a bridge explicitly

Comment: Settings `ClientOnly 0` does *nothing* because they've set an `ORPort`, setting `PublishServerDescriptor bridge` does *nothing* because they've already set `BridgeRelay 1`. Wrong again, Alexey.

Comment: they *should* be set, you're correct, but in cases of bridge announcement problem the metod I proposed helped twice.

Comment: anyway it didn't work

Comment: how much time have you used to check it? what is your criteria of measuring is it working or not? have you tried your bridge from outside?